# How to find tangent of ellipse with slope?

Tags: calculus

It says to find the equation of a tangent line with a slope of m = $\frac{-2}{9}$ to ellipse $4x^2+9y^2=40$.

I have y' = $\frac{-4x}{9y}$. I don't understand what to do next. How can I find the values of x and y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Compare both the slopes, you get:
$$2x=y$$
As this point $(x,y)$ must lie on the ellipse, 
Use that $$4x^2+9y^2=40$$
$$\implies 4x^2+9(2x)^2=40$$
Solve for $x$ and then find $y$,

You now have $(x,y)$ , the point of tangency, now you can write the equation of the tangent.

(You have it's slope and $1$ point lying on it)

Comment: So I subtract the slope of the first equation from the slope of y'?

Comment: The given slope $\frac{-2}{9}$ would be equal to the slope you found $\frac{-4x}{9}$

Comment: So I have to divide the slopes instead, to get the 2x/y?